# How to create a interface "X" extending List interface and implement X using a abstract class Y with ArrayList

Tags: java

Currently am stuck in a peculiar state. I would like to create an interface X which extends java.util.List interface.

Meantime, I am creating an Abstract class Y which implements "X" partially. However, I don't wish to implement methods of List. Is possible to wire them together using ArrayList?

```
public interface X extends Serializable, Cloneable, List<MessageObject>, RandomAccess {

}


public abstract class Y implements X {
}
```

Regarding the above code, Y needs to implement all methods of ArrayList. Is it possible to workaround this? Even creating one more layer inbetween the class should be fine.

The requirement is "Y" should have all methods and functionality of ArrayList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem with the following solution:

```
/**
 * A runtime representation of a section.
 *
 * The message section encapsulates an array of {@link MessageObject}.
 *
 * @see MessageObject
 */
public interface X extends List, Serializable, Cloneable, RandomAccess {
//Code
}
```

The same in implemeneted by an AbstractClass

```
public abstract class Y extends ArrayList implements MessageSection {

//Code

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to inherit them from ArrayList.

```
public abstract class Y extends ArrayList<MessageObject> implements X {
}
```